# Ajax load dose not display SVG image

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, svg

Please check out this url: http://www.kheshtokhak.com/en/
Enter the website, you will see a SVG color window menu with its texts which are image, click one of them.
After AJAX loading, refresh browser in the new page.
Now again click enter and click top left logo, will see the menu without its texts.
This is the problem! I tried calling images by jQuery in AJAX success but doesn't work, How can I fix it?

This is SVG structure:

```
<svg class="nav menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/en/about-us/introduction" xlink:title="">
<text>About us</text>
<defs>
    <pattern id="text144" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <image xlink:href="http://www.kheshtokhak.com/images/window_text/about_us_en.png" width="163" height="275"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
<path fill="url(#text144)" d="M33 156 l125 -30 l38 108 l-163 167 z"></path>
</a>
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/en/events" xlink:title="">
<text>Events</text>
<defs>
    <pattern id="text145" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <image xlink:href="http://www.kheshtokhak.com/images/window_text/events_en.png" width="285" height="160"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
<path fill="url(#text145)" d="M37 397 l156 -160 l129 47 l-43 113 z"></path>
</a>
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/en/projects/all-projects" xlink:title="">
<text>Projects</text>
<defs>
    <pattern id="text146" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <image xlink:href="http://www.kheshtokhak.com/images/window_text/projects_en.png" width="285" height="160"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
<path fill="url(#text146)" d="M37 401 l242 0 l43 113 l-129 47 z"></path>
</a>
<a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/en/contact-us" xlink:title="">
<text>Contact</text>
<defs>
    <pattern id="text147" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <image xlink:href="http://www.kheshtokhak.com/images/window_text/contact_en.png" width="163" height="275"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
<path fill="url(#text147)" d="M33 397 l163 167 l-38 108 l-125 -30 z"></path>
</a>
</svg>
```

and all images are between patterns.

Comment: web can not suggest anything without source code.... please post some

Comment: Look at your console. I see a lot of 404 errors. Apparently, you are trying to load `http://www.kheshtokhak.com/images/music.mp3` but failed.

Comment: @DanielCheung thank you, this is not issue, problem is about loading image in SVG, Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Xoce, thank you, I added SVG structure.